# How can I can modify, using a batch file, the time stamp (last modified) of all files and subdirectories

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am looking to change the last modified time stamp of all my files and directories in "My documents". The reason is that all documents older than 3 months get deleted on the server I am using. This is just a trick to keep my documents as I often need them again after a longer period of time.

What I managed so far with the code below is to change the time stamp "last modified" of all files, including in the subdirectories. But it doesn't change the time stamp of the subdirectories themselves.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /b /s') do (
pushd "%%a"
copy  /B /Y  *.*+,,
popd
)
```

I got this piece of code after some research, but do not understand it fully...
I hope you guys can help

Comment: Create a temporary random file and delete it immediately afterwards; this should change the last modification date of the parent directory...

Comment: There are ways to do this as I am sure you will find. I think you should consider why the files older than three (3) months are deleted. This may be a legal policy of the organization. If that is the retention policy of the organization, perhaps you should comply. Circumventing this may have legal consequences.

Comment: @Liturgist I have asked my boss (CEO). This has been introduced to avoid employees to save personal files in "My documents".
I am not interested in saving personal files there, but would rather be able to store my meeting notes etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it with the following code.
As @aschipfl suggested, I created a random file and then immediately deleted it afterwards

```
@echo off
copy  /B /Y  *.*+,, >nul
echo. > randomfile.txt
if exist randomfile.txt del randomfile.txt /Q
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /b /s') do (
pushd "%%a"
copy  /B /Y  *.*+,, >nul
echo. > randomfile.txt
if exist randomfile.txt del randomfile.txt /Q
popd
)
cls
echo All files and folders updated %date% %time%
pause
```